# Echo ACF color picker value inside foreach loop for WP tags

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, taxonomy

I have a foreach loop to display all the tags of my project. Each Tag must have a colour associated with it, and I am using ACF to create this field on the tags dashboard.

However, when I try to display the value from color picker inside my foreach loop it just doesn't work.

I just can't see what I am doing wrong.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
$tagslist = get_tags();
                                foreach($tagslist as $tag) { 

                                ?>
                        <li>
                            <p><?php echo get_field('tag_color'); ?></p>
                            <a class="tag-list_item theme-<?php echo $tag->slug; ?>" data-tag="<?php echo $tag->term_id; ?>" href="<?php echo get_tag_link($tag->term_id); ?>" stye>
                                 <?php echo $tag->name; ?>
                            </a>

                        </li>
                            
                            <?php }
                        ?>
```

The name of the field that I made is "tag_color".

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get field from tags:

```
<?php
$tagslist = get_tags();
foreach($tagslist as $tag) { 
?>
    <li>
        <p><?php echo get_field('tag_color', 'post_tag_'.$tag->term_id); ?></p>
        <a class="tag-list_item theme-<?php echo $tag->slug; ?>" data-tag="<?php echo $tag->term_id; ?>" href="<?php echo get_tag_link($tag->term_id); ?>" stye>
             <?php echo $tag->name; ?>
        </a>
    </li>                        
<?php } ?>
```

Below is the reference link:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/

Comment: That works perfectly. I tried a similar solution before but forgot the word "post". Thank you so much!